# Remove recommended dependencies of installed package without uninstalling the package nor its actual dependencies with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, uninstall

I want to remove the recommended packages of a package using `apt`.

`my-package` is installed, and I want to keep it and its dependencies.

```
apt-cache depends <my-package> | grep Recommends
```

returns a variety of packages, none of which I want.

How can I remove these packages? I can write a bash script to do it but I'm hoping there's an `apt` way to do it.

I have searched online and haven't found a way to uninstall these recommended packages *without uninstalling the package itself and its required dependencies*. In other words, I want to keep `my-package` and its dependencies, but remove the packages it recommends.

Furthermore I ideally don't want to edit config files; I want to keep the system settings untouched.

Comment: You can construct an aptitude search command, but the easiest way I've found to do this is to just use `apt-cache` and `grep` like you have, then use the mouse to copy-paste the unwanted package names to an `apt-get purge` command line.  It's just not something I do often enough to be worth the bother of learning a single-use specialised tool.  If you want to get fancy, you can use `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` instead of `grep` to get rid of the commas and version numbers and alternations.

Comment: Warning: be careful - uninstalling a package that's only Recommended by one package may end up uninstalling other packages that actually Depend on it.   Use `apt`'s `-d` (`--download-only`) option as a dry-run so you don't accidentally uninstall stuff you didn't mean to.

Comment: I suspect the most straightforward option *is* to uninstall the main package with `--autoremove` and then install it with `--no-install-recommends`. If you `remove` rather than `purge`, you shouldn’t lose anything, other than downtime if any of the removed-and-reinstalled packages provide services. This would also avoid the explicit removal of packages and the consequences mentioned by cas above.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-cache depends my-package \
| grep Recommends: \
| sed "s/Recommends:/sudo apt-get --purge autoremove/;s/<//;s/>//;s/|//" \
| sudo bash
```

---

In my case, `my-package` is `pop-desktop` and the recommended packages are the preinstalled packages on [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/). This is a great way to remove the preinstalled apps! (Be wary though, this does uninstall the Pop!_Shop as well.)

Specifically for Pop!_OS, it is also useful to do

```
sudo apt-get --purge -y autoremove "^libreoffice.*" && sudo reboot
```

because they seem to give `libreoffice` is slightly different section in the UI that is unaddressed by the aforementioned command.